# entity framework core 2 doesn't see sqlite extensions

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

So with entity framework 1.1 I had entities like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Resolution>()
      .Property(r => r.Created)
      .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
      .ForSqliteHasColumnType("Timestamp")            
      .ForSqliteHasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");

 modelBuilder.Entity<Resolution>()
      .Property(r => r.Updated)
      .ForSqliteHasColumnType("Timestamp")
      .IsRequired();
```

which worked fine.  After upgrading to .net core 2.0 and entity framework 2.0 the

```
 .ForSqliteHasColumnType("Timestamp")
```

doesn't seem to be available anymore.  In fact all "ForSqlite*" functions aren't there.

I upgraded the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" to 2.0.   I have

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Did they change something?  I can't seem to find anything in the docs other then the sql providers are not backwards compatible to .NET Core 1.1.

Thanks

Comment: Those methods were removed in 2.0 release. A section of https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8923#issuecomment-310242378 covers it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find anywhere said about the changes. But you can use below code instead in EF Core 2.0.

```
.HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after upgrading a testproject to EF Core 2.0 yesterday, in my case the database was not SQLite, but MS SQL Server.

I had to replace

```
 b.Property(e => e.StartDate).IsRequired().ForSqlServerHasColumnType("Date"); 
 b.Property(e => e.LastModified).IsRequired().ForSqlServerHasColumnType("SmallDateTime");
```

with:

```
 b.Property(e => e.StartDate).IsRequired().HasColumnType("Date"); 
 b.Property(e => e.LastModified).IsRequired().HasColumnType("SmallDateTime");
```

But after that it was working again. I tested it by recreating the database and visually checking the newly created column definitions in MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yea, that's what I ended up doing.